# OneLiner to check if file exists in perl

Tags: perl

In my `httpd.conf` file I want to execute the following filter only, if the file `tmp` doen't exists:

```
ExtFilterDefine htmlfilter mode=output intype=text/html cmd="/usr/bin/perl -pe 's|Mountainbike|BLUE|e unless q{\"\\Q/path/to/my.test.file/.tmp\E\"}'"
```

Right now it is not working. I guess the part `q{...}` is wrong. What do I have to change?

Comment: Well, `q{}` is the operator to emulate single quotes, `''`, so you are saying `unless "string"`, which is (almost) always going to be true. My guess is that you want a file test before the string, i.e. `unless -e "...."`. I guess you think the string is a regex, so you can remove the `\Q .. \E` escape sequence, because it is actually a string, where it is not useful.

Answer (score 1):

Perl uses the `-e` or `-f` to test existence of a file. `q{}` is just a fancy way of writing single quotes.

Also, the `/e` modifier of the substitution evaluates the replacement as code. Are you sure you want to run the BLUE subroutine and replace `Mountainbike` with its return value?

```
cmd="/usr/bin/perl -pe 's/Mountainbike/BLUE/ unless -f q{/path/to/my.test.file/.tmp}'"
```

Comment: Note that this stats the file for every line of the input file

Comment: @ikegami That is a good observation. Perhaps it should be a one-time check, such as `last if -f q{...}` before the substitution. Or a BEGIN block.

Comment: So I did it like the following: `ExtFilterDefine jsonfilter mode=output intype=application/json cmd="/usr/bin/perl -pe 's|^|qq(\,\") . valid . qq(\"\: ) . qq(\") . time() . \\x0D . qq(\") . qq(\\n)|e if ($==eof) &&  unless (-f q{/tmp/md5_filter.tmp})'"`. But the I guess my `&&` operater is not valid. This way it doesn't work. What's wrong?

Comment: The first condition treats to add the timestamp only at the end of the requested file. Do I still need to this code `last if -f q{...}`?

Comment: @TLP @ikegami - I edit my code and insert an `END block`. Will this prevent to check every single line of the file? `cmd="/usr/bin/perl -pe 'END { unless (-f q{/tmp/md5_filter.tmp}) { print qq(\/*) . time() . qq(\*/) } }'"`. Or should I change the `END block` into a `last` statement?